# SuiteCRM api v8 not giving any response

Tags: suitecrm

I want to upgrade my SuiteCRM to latest generation of SuiteCRM versions. Since I am using REST API4.1 for my existing SuiteCRM and came to know that I have to use API v8 for latest generation of SuiteCRM versions, I installed SuiteCRM 7.11.3 with dummy data on our demo server running on https with PHP version 7.1.17.

After this, I generated "client_id" and "client_secret" for "Client Credentials" Grant type by navigating at "Admin" - "OAuth2 Clients and Tokens" - "New Client Credentials Client" on this.

Now I am checking the CRM API for Authentication with Client Credentials and trying to obtain a session using below code but neither getting any array or session nor any error for this.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$header = array(
    'Content-type: application/vnd.api+json',

    'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',

);

$postStr = json_encode(array(

    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',

    'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',

    'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'

));

$url = 'https://url/Api/access_token';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postStr);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$output = curl_exec($ch);


$tab = json_decode($output);

print_r($tab);

curl_close($ch);
```

I have tried by adding "'scope' => ''" in $postStr as suggested in one of posts but did not return anything.

Can anyone please guide regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you generate your private and public keys first or it wont work. https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/version-8/json-api/#_before_you_start_calling_endpoints

Also your post variables should be in the body.

Comment: instead of posting links, better to add relevant code in the answer.